# import error during running my server in django project

Tags: django

Stack Trace:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f535a380938>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/kamal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kamal/Desktop/mywebsite/mywebsite/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ImportError: No module named urls
```

Comment: Try formatting your post and give us some more information on what you've tried and how you've setup your project.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be following the documentation for Django 2.0, but you are using Python 2.7 so you must be using an older version of Django. Make sure you follow the documentation for the version of Django you actually have.